# Transform Rascal ASTs into Famix metamodel

Tags: rascal

is there any support for transforming a Rascal AST into Famix meta model (from Moose technology)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rascal uses M3 meta-models that can, in principle, be easily converted to Famix (but you would have to write that mapping yourself).

There is M3 support for several languages (and the support is growing) so it also depends on the language you are interested in whether there is support for fact extraction from your source.

Comment: I was wondering that, since Rascal has front-end support for different languages, a generic transformation from Rascal ASTs (or M3 meta-models) into Famix would simplify the process of analyzing and visualizing source code using the existing tools of Moose technology.

Comment: Yes, that would be 

Comment: Actually you can find an experimental one here: https://github.com/onierstrasz/rascal-m3-to-mse

Comment: That is great. I will take a look at this experimental project. Hope that I could contribute to it. Thanks!